# How do you style Google forms (from Google Docs)?

Tags: forms, google-workspace

While Google makes themes available to style forms in Google Docs, there seems to be no provision for styling forms yourself.

I have a two-column layout and want the form on the right. There are various problems, such as the textarea overflowing the column. Since it's in an Iframe there's not way to wedge in a stylesheet or a jQuery/javascript fix.

The only suggestion I've found is grabbing the source of the iframe and dropping it into my own HTML, but this breaks the built-in validation and is too hack-ish.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to the do something similar and really struggled in the end the best help i found was on this site:

[Styling google docs forms](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/styling-google-docs-forms.html)

[Customise google forms](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/05/customize-google-docs-forms.html)

Comment: I tried it a bit bit there's no way to set the overall width of the elements. It sucks that this great tool is so limited.

Comment: Yep i guess they have certain user cases for the product, it took me a while to figure out what i wanted to do in the end updated the page mark up to work with the form.